# Scraping new ESPN site using xpath [Python]

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to scrape the new ESPN NBA scoreboard. Here is a simple script which should return the start times for all games on 4/5/15:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

doc =  lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard?date=20150405').text)

#xpath
print doc.xpath("//title/text()") #print page title
print doc.xpath("//span/@time")
print doc.xpath("//span[@class='time']")
print doc.xpath("//span[@class='time']/text()")

#CCS Selector
sel = CSSSelector('span.time')
for i in sel(doc):
    print i.text
```

It doesn't return anything, but the page title:

```
['NBA Basketball Scores - NBA Scoreboard - ESPN']
[]
[]
[]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I have written something that scrapes espn nba, https://github.com/GiannisIordanou/ESPN-NBA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nature of the page is quite dynamic - there are asynchronous XHR requests, javascript logic involved. `requests` is not a browser and downloads only the initial HTML page and there are no `span` elements with `class="time"` in the HTML that `requests` gets.

One of the options to approach the problem would be to involve a real browser using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Here is an example using `PhantomJS` headless browser:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> url = "http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard?date=20150405"
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get(url)
>>> 
>>> elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.time")
>>> for element in elements:
...     print element.text
... 

1:00 PM ET
3:30 PM ET
6:00 PM ET
7:00 PM ET
7:30 PM ET
9:00 PM ET
9:30 PM ET
```

---

Alternatively, you can look for the desired data in the `data-data` attribute of the `div` with `id="scoreboard-page"`:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

import lxml.html
import requests

response = requests.get('http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard?date=20150405')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)

data = doc.xpath("//div[@id='scoreboard-page']/@data-data")[0]
data = json.loads(data)

pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. What other options are there that don't involve using a real browser?

Comment: This is great, thanks. I wish I could give you 2 correct answer checks!!

Comment: This is a really great answer!