# Python HTML Parser - No text inside span

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I did a python script to parse HTML from http://goldprice.org/.

I want my script to get the text inside
`<span class="gpoticker-price" id="gpotickerLeft_price">1,239.45</span>`

[image]

The issue : **There is no text inside de targeted span.**

[image]

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I suspect there's nothing wrong with your code, just that that value appears to be generated via Javascript. Browsers modify their copy of the HTML file when Javascript instructs them to. Since you don't have a Javascript interpreter, you only get the actual version of the HMTL file before JS inserts the value dynamically.

Comment: Ok @AkshatMahajan, how can I get the version of the HTML file after JS inserts the value ?

Comment: A question that has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506547/web-scraping-javascript-in-python-r/36506629#36506629

Comment: Captain here: Selenium | *flies away*

Comment: @Johnrednex This one has a good answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29442025/2998271

Comment: @ErdinEray I took a look at Selenium. Seems good.

Comment: @har07 thank you, it's what I was looking for.